# ElasticSearch to NVD3 in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, elasticsearch, nvd3.js

I'm trying to pass data from and ES query in Angularjs to NVD3 for visualization, but i'm a newbie with JS and trying to figure it out.  I see that it expects a single array with k/v pairs, but how do i convert the data being returned to that format?

My query:

```
 esClient.search({
        index: 'unitedstates',
        size: 5,
        body: {
            query: {
                "match_all" : {}               
            },
            facets: {
                  tagcloud: {
                    terms: {
                      field: 'state'          
                    }
                  }
                }      
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.data = resp.facets.tagcloud.terms; 
    });
```

The result of resp:

```
Array[10]
  0: Object
    count: 986
    term: "virginia"
    __proto__: 
Object1: 
Object2: 
Object3: 
Object4
```

From NVD3, they expect that in the form of below from the website (http://nvd3.org/examples/pie.html)

```
return  [
      { 
        "label": "One",
        "value" : 29.765957771107
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Two",
        "value" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Three",
        "value" : 32.807804682612
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Four",
        "value" : 196.45946739256
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Five",
        "value" : 0.19434030906893
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Six",
        "value" : 98.079782601442
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Seven",
        "value" : 13.925743130903
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Eight",
        "value" : 5.1387322875705
      }
    ];
```

Comment: Do a console.dir(resp) in firebug or Chrome dev tools to see what ES returns. Then update your data as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that correctly, you could just do

```
$scope.data = [];
for (var i=0; i<resp.length; ++i) {
  $scope.data.push({
    label: resp[i].term,
    value: resp[i].count
  });
}
```